Cookies cant be recognized when hosting on Vercel
I'm building myself a project using MERN(Vite). Front end and Backend are hosted separately on Vercel .The Auth system is using JWT . When I hosted them separately in localhost , all the functions works , the JWT can verify the token saved inside cookies , and the backend can print the hash of the token . However , when I hosted them on vercel , I checked the front end can't read the cookies saved , and the log of the backend server said it's undefined when printed.
Front end:
vercel.json
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd());
  console.log("VITE_BACKVER:", env.VITE_BACKVER); // Add a debug log

  return {
    plugins: [react()],
    server: {
      proxy: {
        "/api": {
          target: env.VITE_BACKVER, // Use manually loaded env
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,
        },
      },
    },
  };
});


.env.development
VITE_BACKVER=http://localhost:8080

.env.production
VITE_BACKVER=https://profolio-back-2v.vercel.app

Component to send post
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/AuthContext";

const Write = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

  // Initialize state safely to avoid potential null/undefined errors
  const [comment, setComment] = useState({
    email_blog: currentUser?.email || "",
    uid: currentUser?.userid || "",
    fullname_blog: currentUser?.fullname || "",
    title: "",
    content: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setComment((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };

  const handleClick = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const apiUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKVER;
      const res = await axios.post(`${apiUrl}/api/posts/addpost`, comment, {
        withCredentials: true, // Include cookies in the request
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      console.log(res.data);
      window.location.reload();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error posting comment:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md">
        <h3 className="text-lg font-bold mb-2">Add a comment</h3>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="title">
            Title
          </label>
          <input
            name="title"
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="title"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter title"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
            htmlFor="content"
          >
            Comment
          </label>
          <textarea
            name="content"
            className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
            id="content"
            rows="3"
            placeholder="Enter your comment"
            onChange={handleChange}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button
          className="bg-cyan-500 hover:bg-cyan-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          type="submit"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Write;


BACKEND:
vercel.json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "index.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }],
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/api/(.*)", "destination": "/index.js" }],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value": "https://profolio-front-2v.vercel.app"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization"
        },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "production",
    "JWT_SECRET": "@jwt_secret"
  }
}


function to generate JWT
export function generateToken(payload) {
  // console.log("JWT_SECRET during generation:", process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  if (!secret) {
    throw new Error("JWT secret is not defined");
  }
  return jwt.sign(payload, secret, { expiresIn: "1h" });
}

logic to generate jwt
export const login = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db("profolio");

      const users = database.collection("users");
      const user = await users.findOne({ email });

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "User not found" });
      }

      const isPasswordValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
      if (!isPasswordValid) {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Incorrect password" });
      }

      const token = generateToken({ id: user.email }, "jwtkey");
      res.cookie("access_token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "/",
        sameSite: "Strict",
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 3600 * 1000,
        // domain: '.your-domain.com'
      });

      console.log("Cookie set:", req.cookies.access_token); // Log cookie to check

      return res.status(200).json({ message: "User logged in", user });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Database query error:", err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["POST"]);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
};


When Front-end sent post to posts/addpost , it verify the jwt
export const addPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { fullname_blog, title, content } = req.body;

  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  console.log(token);

  if (!token) return res.status(401).json("Not authenticated!");

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, userInfo) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Verification error:", err);
      return res.status(403).json("Token is not valid!");
    }
    console.log("User info:", userInfo.id);

    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db("profolio");
      const blog = database.collection("blog");
      const newPost = {
        title,
        content,
        email_blog: userInfo.id,
        date: new Date(),
        fullname_blog,
      };
      const result = await blog.insertOne(newPost);

      return res.json("Post has been created.");
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err); // Handle the error appropriately
    } finally {
      await client.close();
    }
  });
};


So when i use local host , the cookies can be printed
but in vercel , it only give me
res.status(401).json("Not authenticated!");
want want someone can answer my question or give me some directions

Your backend is creating the access_token cookie with sameSite=Strict, per docs, this means it won't sent the cookie in your frontend request if it's coming from a different domain. If that is your case, you might need to try with SameSite=None; Secure.
